# SQL query using Look up table to select number of records based on a day

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I have to select specific number of records based on the day. For ex: on day 08/15 I only wanted to select 1000 records and 2000 customers on 08/16 and 5000 customers on 08/17 and so on.... there is no specific order but will have to do this for a period of 1 month. This information is static and won't change, so I created a static table as below and I had to join this to another table called driver to extract other columns like balance, payment etc. Driver table has almost 1 million records and doesn't have any join column to join to this static table, I thought of using timestamp column and extract day from it and use it as join. I am a recent passed out and new to sql so please let me know how this can be achieved.

Table: Static

| Day | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 08/15 | 1000 |
| 08/16 | 2000 |
| 08/17 | 5000 |
| 08/18 | 9000 |

Table: Driver

| Payment | Outstanding | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 560 | abc | NY |
| 08/16 | 780 | 123 | WA |
| 08/17 | 940 | xyz | NJ |
| 08/18 | 1000 | nop | TX |

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using.

Comment: Just use [some joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) you can experiment here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a date in the second table, you would use a `join` with `row_number()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from driver d
     ) d join
     static s
     on d.date = s.day
where seqnum <= s.count;
```

Comment: Cool thanks @gordon linoff, will try this and let you know if this works